# R geographically weighted regression with negative binomial distribution

Tags: r, geographically-weighted-regression

I'm trying to find a R package that allows me to do geographically weighted negative binomial regression. I'm aware there's 'spgwr' and 'glm.nb' package. But is there a package that combines the two? If not, is it possible to change one of the package to meet my aim, for example adding negative binomial distribution to 'spgwr'?